# pass a parameter in setAttribute "onclick" function argument in javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: line 163]

Here in line no 163 I want to set a function to the close item . close is a button here . And I want to pass a parameter through it's "onclick" event. that is it's id. How do I do it?

Comment: You should include your code inside the question - not as a screenshot;;; Have you tried removing the "'s from around checker('id') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use an event listener in this case instead of try to manipulate the onclick with setAttribute:

```
close.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //do what you need here: call another function, do some math, etc...
    checker('id'); //???
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
close.onclick = function(){
    checker('id'); // <-- are you sure you want to pass static string here?
};
```